# arsort works properly but what doesn't?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Calling `die(var_dump($dias));` returns:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => float 0.079
      1 => float 0.103
      2 => float 0.128
      3 => float 0.093
      4 => float 0.084
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => float 0.082
      1 => float 0.083
      2 => float 0.094
      3 => float 0.071
      4 => float 0.094
```

With or without `foreach($dias as $k => $v) arsort($dias[$k]);` it returns the same thing.

How can I reorder the arrays without losing the key reference?

Comment: What about: `foreach ($dias as &$sub) rsort($sub);`?

Comment: Your code looks good. That part is not where you do the error. Reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14449189/367456

Comment: Found the error. It was inside another foreach loop that had odd iterations... so it was a dumb mistake. Thank you all.

Comment: @BrunnoBenatti: Yeah, like I wrote. Happy debugging.

Answer (score 4):

To modify the value of a php array inside of a foreach, you have to precede your `$v` with an ampersand a la `foreach($dias as $k => &$v)`. Then use `artsort($v)` to sort the subarrays; otherwise you're modifying a copy of the value which is not present after the foreach executes. See [the foreach manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for more info.